# Polynomial Between Two Sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let's say we have two sets $A=\{a_0, a_1, ...\}$ and $B=\{b_0, b_1, ...\}$ of equal infinite cardinality (say for simple purposes $\aleph_0$. Is there a general way of determining whether or not a polynomial $P(x)$ exists such that $P(a_i)=P(b_i)$ for all $i$?

Comment: Do you mean $P(a_i)=P(b_i)$ for all $i\ge 0$? Otherwise the answer is trivially in the affirmative.

Comment: The constant polynomial works.